# Is it possible to extend the Solution class?

Tags: java, evolutionary-algorithm, moea-framework

I'm getting an error saying that "org.moeaframework.core.Solution cannot be cast to SensorsSolution".
SensorsSolution is a class that extends Solution. **Does MOEA allow this? It's a recomended practice?**

The reason i'm extending it, is because i need each individual to store information about sensors locations.
After evaluating the use of the attributes HashMap of this class and realizing that it's data erases after each evaluation i decided it was the best option. But now i'm facing this problem.

Heres the code that corresponds to the error line:

```
@Override
public void evaluate(Solution solution) {
    System.out.println("class= "+solution.getClass()); //Returning "class SensorsSolution"
    SensorsSolution sensorsSolution = (SensorsSolution) solution;
    ...
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Without any code it is hard to help. However it seems like you try to cast either Solution or a derived class, which is **not** SensorSolution to SensorSolution . I would recommend you print out the full classname of the object you try to cast,

Comment: Ok, i will add some code and the output of the classname. Thanks!

Comment: @Maksim Its done!

Comment: Could you change your code to `System.out.println("class= "+solution.getClass().getCanonicalName())`  ? Because there might be a class of the same name but a different package...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is to save extra information about each function evaluation, information that is computed but not included in the objectives or constraints.  This is a frequent request by users of MOEAs.  You're on the right track modifying the `evaluate` method to do *something*, but I suspect you'd be better off writing the extra information to a SQLite database, HDF5 file, or even a text file.  Generally you want to look this information up at the end of the run -- it's not going to do much for you during the run.